# No L2TP VPN option on Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)?

Tags: vpn, 23.04, l2tp

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) to Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster), the "Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol (L2TP)" option is no longer available in the "Add VPN" dialog ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2eeu.png)) in Settings > Network > VPN. How, if at all, can I still add an L2TP VPN connection in Ubuntu 23.04?
[image]

Comment: You have to install it.  However, keep in mind that L2TP isn't necessarily the *safest* of VPN solutions out there, it has a lot of limitations.  You can attempt to install `networkmanager-l2tp{,-gnome}` to add it to Network Manager, but it's no longer part of the *default set* of Network Manager plugins.